# Advanced jquery/flash player for youtube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, youtube

How to implement advanced video player(javascript/jquery/flash) for youtube videos that supports playlists?
Is there some good open source script for this, that I could modify.

I would like player similar to ones used on jukesy.com or grooveshark.com.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this example.](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16007/playlists-with-thumbnail-images)

Playlist.xml from the example:

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:jwplayer="http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/" 
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"> 
  <channel> 
    <title>Playlist with Thumbnails</title> 
    <item> 
      <title>Big Buck Bunny Trailer</title> 
      <media:content url="/videos/bunny.mp4" /> 
      <media:thumbnail url="/thumbs/bunny.jpg" />
      <jwplayer:playlist.image>/thumbs/bunny_small.jpg</jwplayer:playlist.image> 
      <jwplayer:duration>33.03</jwplayer:duration> 
    </item> 
    <item> 
      <title>Sintel</title> 
      <media:content url="/videos/sintel.mp4" /> 
      <media:thumbnail url="/thumbs/sintel.jpg" />
      <jwplayer:playlist.image>/thumbs/sintel_small.jpg</jwplayer:playlist.image> 
      <jwplayer:duration>888.06</jwplayer:duration> 
    </item> 
    <item> 
      <title>Elephant&#39;s Dream</title> 
      <media:content url="/videos/elephant.mp4" /> 
      <media:thumbnail url="/thumbs/elephant.jpg" /> 
      <media:thumbnail>/thumbs/elephant.jpg</media:thumbnail> 
      <jwplayer:playlist.image>/thumbs/elephant_small.jpg</jwplayer:playlist.image> 
      <jwplayer:duration>653.79</jwplayer:duration> 
    </item> 
  </channel> 
</rss>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>
```

Embed code from the example:

```
<div id='mediaplayer'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '650',
    'height': '240',
    'playlistfile': 'playlist.xml',
    'playlist.position': 'right',
    'playlist.size': '250'
  });
</script>
```